# How to find what keywords to target in large scale?

Tags: seo, keywords, tools

Currently we have a website with more than 300000 indexed pages and everyday there are 600 new pages added, the website is a news website.

The strategy is that we start finding what keywords we should target and then start creating content and building links, etc. We know Google Trends, but we don't know about how to find 5000 keyword we should target (as an example 5000). Any ideas?

Comment: http://moz.com/beginners-guide-to-seo/keyword-research

Comment: I do not have any recommendations, but it sounds like you need a keyword tool designed to (bare with me) spamdex search engines or for large scale blogs. They are designed for large sites and keyword automation. Not all of them are designed specifically spandexing of course, but it sounds like you are walking right up to that line where these tools can really help you plan your keyword strategy. I suspect they can really help. Otherwise, I would just let your content speak for itself. This is what Google wants anyway and you would get long-tail search more than topical short-term search.

Comment: This tool is quite usefull, uses Google auto sugges to generate keyword ideas: http://keywordtool.io/

Comment: It sounds like you need something robust. I use SEO PowerSuite but it is not cheap! http://www.seopowersuite.com/ I can highly recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

I would take Google Webmaster Tools impression data and use that to generate a list of related keywords.

There are several services that you can you for keyword analysis and generation. I like using [Market Samurai](http://seobandwagon.com/out/market-samurai/), it's easy enough for a beginner and powerful enough to keep using it as you get more advanced. It will run through a variety of keyword metrics and analyze the competition, marketability, and frequency usage of that phrase using Google AdWords, Bing, and Majestic SEO.